# JSoup: parse Twitter list

Tags: twitter, jsoup

I want to parse a Twitter list (e.g. https://twitter.com/spdbt/lists/spd-bundestagsabgeordnete/members) using JSoup. My problem is, that the page is dynamic, i.e. that I only get the first 20 results from the page. Is there any way JSoup can fetch the whole page?

Currently, my codes looks as follows:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(listAdress).get();
Elements usernames = doc.select(".username.js-action-profile-name");
Elements realNames = doc.select(".fullname.js-action-profile-name");
// iterate over usernames and realNames and do something
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I do not think this is possible : [More info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25749309/using-jsoup-to-parse-a-dynamic-page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally solved the problem by using a Twitter library, but thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Some work around to achieve this

- Launch browser with above URL using Selenium
- Load page fully
- get the page source using Selenium method.
- Pass this content to JSOUP
- Parse it.

Logic

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("https://twitter.com/spdbt/lists/spd-bundestagsabgeordnete/members")
//some logic to scroll or you do it manually
String pageContent = driver.getPageSource();
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(pageContent);
//from here write your logic to get the required values
```