# Jsoup: Find all images on specified page and also on subpages or inside javascript?

Tags: java, android, image, jsoup

When I try to use jsoup [example](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/example-list-links) in my Android app on page like [this](http://globcams.blogspot.cz/), then no images are found. It's because content is loaded through javascript?

Now my code look like this:

```java
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
Elements media = doc.select("[src]");

print("\nMedia: (%d)", media.size());
List<Link> tmpLinks = new ArrayList<>();
int i = 0;
for (Element src : media) {
    if (src.tagName().equals("img")) {
        if (!src.attr("abs:src").contains(".png") && !src.attr("abs:src").contains(".gif")) {
            String widthString = src.attr("width");
            int width;
            if (!widthString.isEmpty()) {
                width = Integer.parseInt(src.attr("width"));
            }
            else width = 0;
            String heightString = src.attr("height");
            int height;
            if (!heightString.isEmpty()) {
                height = Integer.parseInt(src.attr("height"));
            }
            else height = 0;

            if (width == 0 || width >= minAllowedWidth) {
                if (!src.attr("abs:src").isEmpty()) {
                    tmpLinks.add(new Link(i, src.attr("abs:src"), width, height));
                }
            }
            i++;
            print(" * %s: <%s> %sx%s (%s)",
                    src.tagName(), src.attr("abs:src"), src.attr("width"), src.attr("height"),
                    trim(src.attr("alt"), 20));
        }
    }
}

List<Link> noDuplicates = new ArrayList<>();
Set<String> titles = new HashSet<>();
for (Link link : tmpLinks ) {
    if (titles.add(link.getUrl())) {
        noDuplicates.add(link);
    }
}

List<Link> finalLinks = new ArrayList<>();
for (Link link : noDuplicates) {
    URL testUrl = new URL(link.getUrl());
    URLConnection urlConnection = testUrl.openConnection();
    urlConnection.connect();
    int file_size = urlConnection.getContentLength();
    System.out.println("Fetching size: " + link.getUrl() + " " + file_size);
    if (file_size >= minAllowedFileSize) {
        link.setSize(file_size);
        finalLinks.add(link);
    }
}
Collections.sort(finalLinks, new LinkSizeComparator());
```

The second question is, can I analyze with jsoup subpages (or image links) on site like [this](http://kamery.humlnet.cz/).

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to crawl the website with Jsoup and I got no images so apparently it doesn't work with dynamic websites.

You could try what the user suggests in this thread
[Getting Jsoup to support dynamically generated html by JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12625043/getting-jsoup-to-support-dynamically-generated-html-by-javascript)

Comment: Thank you Eric, but I forgot to tell you, I use jsoup in Android app, so the linked javascript libraries I cannot use. I try also get html as string from webview, but without success.

Comment: I've been thinking in something but I can't came up with nothing too "easy". I would say : create a webservice which uses HtmlUnit (or another library, if there it is another) then you consume that service from android and you forgot about Jsoup. I can't think of anything else :/.

Comment: Eric, you are right. I thought the same thing. But for me now is using java application on the server side expensive, so maybe in the future. But thank you for your response and tips!