# Jsoup: How Do I Load More Webpage Content in Java?

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsoup

I am currently trying to parse titles from news articles from [yahoo news](http://news.yahoo.com/#) using Jsoup. It works great except for the fact that I only get a limited number of said news articles.

The problem I am trying to tackle is how to get the news that are only loaded once you scroll to the bottom of the webpage when you are in your browser. Is there a way to load those with Jsoup and then parse?

Thanks!

Comment: Jsoup does not support javaScript, so does not support dynamically loading webpages. Use the [Yahoo News api](https://developer.yahoo.com/boss/search/boss_api_guide/news.html) instead.

Comment: can you give me a reference link that jsoup does not support javascript..cant seem to find one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting Jsoup to support dynamically generated html by JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12625043/getting-jsoup-to-support-dynamically-generated-html-by-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

> *can you give me a reference link that jsoup does not support javascript..cant seem to find one.*

Some links from SO itself:

*"Jsoup does not support javascript and it does not emulate a browser(...)"*
[Mosty Mostacho](https://stackoverflow.com/users/268273/mosty-mostacho) - [**Getting Jsoup to support dynamically generated html by JavaScript**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12631861/363573)

*"JSoup is an HTML parser (...) it's completely unaware of any content that is added to the DOM by Javascript after the initial page load."*
[fvu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/112079/fvu) - [**Page content is loaded with javascript and Jsoup doesn't see it**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7489380/363573)

*"JSoup (...) is not a web browser. It excels at parsing static html content. It does not run any javascript, so you are out of luck."*
[luksch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2229229/luksch) - [**Jsoup get dynamically generated HTML**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22400976/363573)

*"JSoup does not process Javascript."*
[N K](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5262426/n-k) - [**Extracting “hidden” HTML with Jsoup**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33906713/363573)